# Mixed Integer and String bytebyffer in java

Tags: java, byte, bytebuffer

I have a bytebuffer in java that is a mix of string and integer types, here is the code to get a better idea of what I mean.

```
    int ID_SIZE = 8;
    int LENGTH_SIZE = 8;
    int MESSAGE_SIZE = 30;
    char[] id = new char[ID_SIZE];
    int length = 12;
    String message = "\0";
    for(int i = 0;i<MESSAGE_SIZE;i++)
        message+="a";
    ByteBuffer bbuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(35);
    bbuf.putInt(length);
    bbuf.put(message.getBytes());
    for(int i = 0;i<36;i++)
        System.out.println(bbuf.get(i));
```

and as the result I get

```
0
0
0
12
0
97
97
97
97
97
97
97
97
97
97
97
97
97
97
97
97
97
97
97
97
97
97
97
97
97
97
97
97
97
97
```

I know the `97` is ASCII `a`. However I am curious as to why before the `12` it is `0` `0` `0`? Does this have anything to do with it being a mixed bytebuffer or is this just normal byetbuffer behavior?

Comment: You might find the [documentation for ByteBuffer.putInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#putInt-int-) helpful.

Comment: @VGR actually had just figured that out. But now am curious, why when I put a number such as 150 does it display `0` `0` `0` `-56` instead of using all 4 to sum to 150?

Comment: Because that's what you get when you treat 150 as a signed byte.  If n >= 128, then n as a signed byte is n - 256.

Comment: @jgr208 if it just used four values to sum to the `int` value, you wouldn't be able to store values of more than 1024.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're storing a 32-bit integer. Each byte that you see when you print out your byte buffer is 8 bits long; so it takes four of them to represent a 32-bit value.

Note that the two implementations of `ByteBuffer` that come with the JDK use big endian by default, so you're getting `00 00 00 12` rather than `12 00 00 00`. You can change this with

```
bbuf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
```

if you want, but if you're just storing and retrieving, then it doesn't really matter as long as you retrieve with the same ordering that you store.

For more information on how an `int` gets converted to bytes, you might find [this article](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/datarepresentation.html) rather helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`ByteBuffer.putInt` always puts the int as the full 32 bits -- 4 bytes.  You're seeing the leading three zero bytes in the length field.